# What is the best way to get orbs?

Tags: dauntless

I'm trying to upgrade by fire sword and frost armor but I need more fire and frost orbs. I only get about 2-5 from killing bosses and I was wondering if there was a faster way to get orbs. I'm fairly new (Only level 9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://www.ordinaryreviews.com/2019/05/27/dauntless-how-to-get-frost-orbs/) you can get frost orbs about 10 per monster if you do a frost patrol.

> The best way to farm frost orbs is by doing Patrols under the hunting board. In the board, you should see Pursuits and Patrols.
>   Go for Frost Patrol if you wish to get frost orbs. You’ll face a frost behemoth and you’ll get 10 orbs upon completion.

With the patrol bonus you will get double frost orbs so you would get about 20.

What I've personally learned is that you indeed need to do patrols to get the most orbs of a certain type.